# Add attributes to ActiveRecord from fieldTable

Tags: activerecord, yii

I have an Yii project, where I want to add fields on the profile page, which are described in another model.

So the table could look like this:

```
CREATE  TABLE `object_field` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `varname` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `title` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `field_type` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
  `match` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `range` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `default` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `required` INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  `position` INT(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  `visible` INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

So in the `UserProfile`-model, I have added the fields to the `rules()` and `attributesLabels()` but the `__get()` and `__set()` does can't find the attributes before I add e.g. `public $this->fieldName` to model.

The values to the user is stored in another table, which connects the `User` with the `UserData`

Should I overwrite the `__get()` and `__set()` in the model, or how can I make my fields to the form accept using dynamic defined fields?

**Update:**

I have looked at the Yii-user extension, http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-user/, but it does just change the UserProfile-schema to add the new fields. I could have 20 different types of users, and each of them shares some fields and maybe have some special fields just for the one type.

A solution could be to add the mongoDB as a relation. But I have never worked with that technology.

Comment: I think you're not being clear enough

Comment: Wouldn't be there a relation `UserProfile HAS_MANY objectFields`? E.g.  you need `ObjectField.user_profile_id` attribute. If you want to allow reusing object fields then you need an intermediate table for holding groups/roles.